# How to fix new chrome driver's exception - WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: value must be a non-negative integer

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am running a test case that I have been running for months.

Yesterday I updated Chrome to the latest release (75.0.3770.100), also I downloaded the compatible version of chrome driver (75.0.3770.90). After these updates, I tried to run the same test case and I get the following exception:

```py
"WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: value must be a non-negative integer"
```

How can I manage/fix that?

Is there any workaround?

I am using python 2.7, selenium version 3.5.0, and robot framework version 3.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix the issue by upgrading selenium version to 3.9.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I have updated my recent webdrivers along with the browsers but the IDE was still on old version and some plugins were outdated. 
The issue was resolved once I have updated the IDE (in my case I use Pycharm).

One more thing try to make sure that your project Interpreter set correctly to Python environment something like below:

Python 2.7 (venv) `~/venv/bin/python`